# Seeking FOSS SHA1

Tags: delphi, sha1

I am looking for a FOSS SHA1 implementation for use with Delphi (7).

Preferably something small, maybe even standalone SHA1, rather than past of a humongous library. Ease of install and use are nice, but of course reliability is priority number 1.

---

Update:Thanks, Rob, that code works like a dream

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [Cryptography API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380255.aspx) built in to the OS. You can use the [*Hashes.pas*](http://delphi.jmrds.com/?q=node/36) unit by Domingo Seoane to use it in Delphi, or you can write your own routine using CryptAcquireContext, CryptCreateHash, repeated calls to CryptHashData, and finally CryptGetHashParam to get the result.

I realize it's neither free (as in speech) nor open source, but there are also no distribution requirements since it's included on all your customers' systems already.

Comment: +1 Brilliant! Thanks, Rob. That sounds like an elegant solution.

Comment: +1 - Awesome.  Using CryptoAPI should leave you I/O bound too.

Comment: CryptoAPI is not the fastest around. And with the upcoming cross-platform Delphi IDE, a pure pascal version could make sense for your future projects.

Comment: ok, I know that I am supposed to be able to figure it out by myself, but apparently I am too dumb. That unit itself won't compile ... Undeclared identifier 'HCRYPTPROV'  ... what am I missing? Sorry

Comment: Do you get that error message before or after the line that says `HCRYPTPROV = ULONG`?

Comment: I got the error message after one beer too many :-)   Next morning a quick d'oh! and it works like a dream. Thanks, Rob

Comment: But how to get back string from SHA1?

Comment: I don't understand your question, @Robrok. Aren't you using the Delphi code I linked to?

Comment: Sorry, SHA1 can`t be decoded and that`s why it is called as secure hach algorithm hash or something like that :)

Answer (score 5):

[TurboPower LockBox](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tplockbox/) is free and open-source and implements SHA1, as well as many others:

Features

- AES
- SHA2 (including the new SHA-512/224 & SHA-512/256)
- DES/3DES
- Blowfish
- Twofish
- SHA1
- MD5
- RSA Sign &
  Verify
- Chaining modes: ECB, CBC, CFB8, CFB, CTR, ECB, OFB, PCBC

Version 3 officially supports Delphi 2007 and Delphi 2010 (but may work with Delphi 7), but Version 2 has support for older versions of Delphi.

Comment: +1 +1 thanks, I'll look into it. I also like the look of Jedi, but these both offer more functionality than I need,

Answer (score 5):

You have Open Source MD5, SHA-1, SHA-256, and Adler32 implementation in the [SynCrypto.pas](http://synopse.info/fossil/finfo?name=SynCrypto.pas) unit. There is also included AES-256 encryption.

This unit was very optimized for speed (the SHA-256 an AES-256 was even profiled at asm level), and can also use the very fast real-time instructions of the VIA C3/C7/Nano CPU if available.

Works from Delphi 6 up to XE.

Answer (score 3):

You most probably already have SHA-1 implementation preinstalled within `IdHashSHA1` unit (part of Indy 10).